# Pixbuf shows wrong info about image

Tags: c++, image, user-interface, gtk, gtkmm

No matter what picture I load into Gdk::Pixbuf (using GTKmm) it always shows the same info. I'm taking about functions **get_n_channels()**, **get_bits_per_sample()** and **get_has_alpha()**.

I check images by others programs and they shows different (but correct) information. Help!

Some of my code:

```
Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::Pixbuf> ob = scene.get_pixbuf(); // some image
stringstream out;

out.str("");
out << ob->get_n_channels();
tekst +="Nr. of channels: <b>" + out.str() +"</b>\n";
out.str("");
out << ob->get_bits_per_sample();
tekst +="bits per sample: <b>" + out.str() +"</b>\n";
tekst +="alpha canal: <b>";
if (ob->get_has_alpha())tekst +="yes</b>\n";
else tekst +="no</b>\n";

info.set_markup(tekst); // Gtk::Label
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that GdkPixbuf supports a very limited set of pixel formats:

- RGB color, 8 bits per channel
- 8-bit alpha channel, or no alpha at all

When you load an image with GdkPixbuf, it converts the image to 24-bit RGB, plus 8-bit alpha if the image had transparency.  For example, if you load a grayscale image, it will get "exploded" to RGB channels.  That's why you only ever get GDK_COLORSPACE_RGB out of gdk_pixbuf_get_colorspace(), and 8 out of _get_bits_per_sample().

This is suboptimal, but we only had time to implement *that* when we were initially writing GdkPixbuf.  IrfanView will of course have a more sophisticated idea of image representations - it will show you what the original image file declares, not the internal representation that the image has when it gets decoded.